# Extract parameter from URLs in different forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, uri

How can I fetch id = 123 from the following URLs?

```
"http://www.test.com/user/controller/123/edit?query1='A'"
"http://www.test.com/user/controller/action_name?query1='A'&query2=123"
"http://www.test.com/user/controller/action_name?query2=123&query_3='B'"
"http://www.test.com/user/controller/123/edit"
```

Comment: Just to clarify. You are not using Ruby on Rails and want to get id from REST url string?

Comment: The answer really depends on the framework you are using.

Comment: @KhajaMinhajuddin Not really; parsing strings like this is rather simple in pure Ruby, regardless of any 'framework' that may or may not be in use.

Comment: @Phrogz that's true, but if the OP was using rails, he could have used the params hash to easily get the values. Your answer works too, However, someone might have suggested an easier way to get the info, if he he had mentioned the framework.

Answer (score 2):

```
def q2id(url)
  url[%r{controller/(\d+)},1] or url[%r{query2=(\d+)},1]
end

%w[
  http://www.test.com/user/controller/123/edit?query1='A'
  http://www.test.com/user/controller/action_name?query1='A'&query2=123
  http://www.test.com/user/controller/action_name?query2=123&query_3='B'
  http://www.test.com/user/controller/123/edit
].each{ |url| puts q2id(url) }
#=> 123
#=> 123
#=> 123
#=> 123
```

Or shorter-but-less-clear:

```
def q2id(url)
  url[%r{(?:controller/|query2=)(\d+)},1]
end
```